# npm install throws and error telling node is not a recognized command

Tags: node.js, npm, core-js

[image: system throwing node not found error]

I  have added node to the PATH.
I have tried reinstalling node and restarting the system.
node --version = 6.13.7 
npm --version = 12.14.1

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it states _"DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc -  copy or type the text into the question [instead]"_. Many of the reasons for not doing this are listed in [why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#answer-285557). Please `edit` your question and replace the error/log image with text.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your PC can't pick up on `node` as a command, it's usually a PATH issue.

I note that you say you have already added it to Path, but it's worth checking a few things:

1. Did you add it to User Path or System Path?
2. How long is your Path parameter? If it's too long, you may need to break it down into two or more variables. Reference here: https://www.howtogeek.com/266621/how-to-make-windows-10-accept-file-paths-over-260-characters/
3. Have you added Git to your Path as well? If not, go ahead and install Git Bash: https://gitforwindows.org/
4. If restarting hasn't done the trick of refreshing your env variables for whatever reason, you can force it along by opening Powershell as admin, and running `refreshenv`
5. If you are able to run node commands, but npm isn't able to run them on your behalf, it may be a permissions issue. Consider running the very same command, but in an elevated permissions CMD. (Run CMD as admin)